# If an object moves at constant velocity up a slope, is force=0?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

I have a problem in which I am imagining an object moving up a slope at constant velocity. I have read a book on rollercoaster mechanics ("An engineer's guide to roller coaster design" by Nick Weisenberger) in which an equation was used to show the force pulling a car up a climb-

**KE1 + PE1 + WD = KE2 + PE2**

If the climb was supposed to be done at a constant velocity, say the car was moving at 5 meters per second at the bottom and travelled up to the top of the climb at a constant velocity of 5 meters per second without accelerating, there would be an issue in which energy is created out of nothing-

**0.5m(v)^2 + mgh1+ fd = 0.5m(v)^s + mgh2**

If the velocity is constant then it will cancel out...

**mgh1 + fd = mgh2**

And if velocity is constant, so must be acceleration. **f=ma** so force is also equal to 0

**mgh1 = mgh2**

Seeing as h1 is below h2, how is this possible?!

Comment: Don't plug in random symbols in random equations. You have $f d=m g (h_2-h_1)$ with $h_2-h_1=d \sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle of the track (assuming it's constant). So $f=m g \sin(\theta)$, obviously.

Comment: if velocity is constant it means there is another force in addition to gravity, otherwise the object would reduce its speed as it moves up. So this force is providing energy to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the direction, if an object has **uniform velocity** (moving with the same speed in one direction) the **net force** on the object will be **zero**.

Answer (score 0):

When you use mgh, you have already taken the gravitational force into account implicitly already. So the force you will consider is the net force minus the gravitational force (this is the force used to pull up the roller coaster).

Or you don't think about gravitational potential but treat mg as the gravitational force, then yes, net force is zero (mg=f, d=h2-h1).

Answer (score 0):

> **KE1 + PE1 + WD = KE2 + PE2**

What you are considering is a car on a roller coaster (and the Earth).

**KE1** is the initial kinetic energy of the car and **KE2** is the final kinetic energy of the car.
If the velocity (or speed) does not change then KE1 = KE2, i.e. there is no change in the kinetic energy of the car.

If the car is lifted up the its initial potential energy **PE1** is less than its final potential energy **PE2** and so there is a change in the potential energy of PE2-PE1.
This change of potential energy does not depend on the velocity of the car it only depends on the increase in separation between the car and the Earth.

How is that increase in potential energy achieved?

An external force F acts on the car and moves through a distance d.
The work done by the external force is Fd and that work results in the potential energy of the car changing.

---

I think that your confusion arrises because you are not clear what an external force is.

If you consider the car **alone** you will note that the car is acted on by two external forces.
The external force F and the gravitational attraction of the Earth on the car mg.

If you state that the velocity of the car does not change then there is no acceleration and the net force on the car F-mg must be zero.

The total work done on the car **alone** is zero.

Why have I emphasised the word **alone**?
It is because in your original equation you are not just considering the car but the car **and** the Earth.
It is the car and the Earth together which have potential energy.
Once you consider the car and the Earth the gravitational attraction of the Earth on the car becomes an internal force (its Newton's third law pair being the gravitational attraction on the Earth due to the car) and then you only have one external force, your F.

---

So when you use the equation > **KE1 + PE1 + WD = KE2 + PE2** remember that the external force acting on the car F is doing work and you are using the idea of conservation of energy to go from an initial to final state.